# How do I break from a while loop with a switch?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to break from a while loop in a switch statement but it's not working. I get an infinite loop. Why?

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    while (std::cin >> n)
    {
         switch (n)
         {
         case 4:
             break;
             break;
         default:
             std::cout << "Incorrect";
             break;
         }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because that's not how `break` works. Once the first `break` executes, you exit the `switch` statement and the second `break` never executes. You'll have to find another way to exit the outer control structure. For example, set a flag in the `switch` statement, and then check that flag at the end, or in the loop condition.

```
while (std::cin >> n)
{
    bool should_continue = true;
    switch (n)
    {
    case 4:
        should_continue = false;
        break;
    default:
        std::cout << "Incorrect";
        break;
    }
    if (!should_continue)
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`break` within a `switch` breaks the switch. Do somthing like:

```
while (std::cin >> n)
{
     if(n == 4)
         break;
     switch (n)
     {
     //...Other case labels
    default:
         std::cout << "Incorrect";
         break;
     }
}
```